# handle JSON response with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I tried a long time to handle a JSON response with SwiftyJSON, but I don't know how to parse the response. Here's my code:

```
    var jsonString:String = ""

    Alamofire
        .request(.GET, url + "/HMServer/rest/administration/version")
        .responseJSON {
            (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

            let json = JSON(object: data!)

            //here I want to do something with parsing
    }
```

The requests I do with Alamofire and get back a JSON response. The response look like:

```
[message: [SERVER_VERSION: 0.1, INTERFACE_VERSION: 0.1], type: success]
```

I want to save all elements in strings and give them back. How can I parse the JSON response saved in the let `let json`? I tried to use [Alamofire-SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON) but the code does not work. All examples I found are too old because the SwiftyJSON code was refactored a few days ago.

THX!

Comment: Why don't you use NSJSONSerilization? That's much easier and backed by Apple.

Comment: for me the code is not as easy as alamofire and swiftyjson. do you have an easy example or do you know a good tutorial?

Comment: I'll give you an example but a question first: Is the response you are showing above the response from the server or the parsed version?

Comment: that is the response data from alamofire. if i do **println(json)** in the code above, then i get the posted response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed [Alamofire-SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON)'s issue,
but you can do it by yourself in responseJSON's closure like:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url + "/HMServer/rest/administration/version")
         .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                self.swiftyJSON = SwiftyJSON.JSON.Null(error)
            } else if object != nil {
                self.swiftyJSON = SwiftyJSON.JSON(object: object!)
            } else {
                self.swiftyJSON = SwiftyJSON.JSON.Null(nil)
            }
}
```

Above code is not like [Alamofire-SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON) in the global queue, the initialization (AnyObject to SwiftyJSON) is running in the main queue.

Comment: What is `self.swiftyJSON` for a type?

Comment: I solved the problem. In my function now I return the whole JSON enum. And later I parse it like `jsonReturn["message"]["HMSERVER_VERSION"].stringValue`. It runs for me :)